# laravel 5 Ajax without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, laravel-5

Im having problems with sending an ajax request using laravel 5.

This is what kicks of the ajax request when clicked.

```
<td>
    <i data-service="{{$performer['serviceID']}}" class="fa fa-eye"></i>{{$performer['name'] }}
</td>
```

Ajax code

```
$(function() {
    $('.fa-eye').click(function () {
        var service = $(this).attr('data-service');

        jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "/addWatchList",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                console.log(token);
                if (token) {
                    return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                }
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            data: {
                service: service
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                //alert("xhr=" + xhr + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
            }
        });
        alert('went past ajax');
    });
});
```

Now my ajax request isn't even reaching my controller.

The error i get is xhr=[object Object] b=parsererror c=SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: so you are getting an error from your servier functions.. that results an xhr object. if you want to access it. you can debug your code (like inserting breakpoints) and than check the properties of xhr :)

Comment: How would i do this?

Comment: use the browser console.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: I know about the console. but what do i look for in their?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not an answer to your question, but if you want to pass the token, just add

```
"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
```

to your `data`.